# Adding a title properly in Android Studio Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I do a chat application now and I want to give the chat room a title of the person I'm going to write to. The problem is that I don't know how I can align it properly inside my chat layout without making my textview go inside the listview itself. Here is my xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="il.co.appschool.firebasechatapp.ChatActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_above="@id/fab"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, my textview is in the top of the file, but I can't align it so that it won't go inside my listview. Can you pls help me and tell me what to write in order to make it look good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Use **`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`** in your **`TextView`**
 and  **`android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"`** in your  **`ListView`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="il.co.appschool.firebasechatapp.ChatActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dsd"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_above="@id/fab"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Comment: Can you tell what you changed? I just copied everything because i couldn't see what you changed

Comment: @EliKozinets please check my ans again i ahve make your textview **`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`** and your listview **`android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"`**

Comment: @EliKozinets happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

put your list view below the text view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="il.co.appschool.firebasechatapp.ChatActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sampleText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 `enter code here`android:layout_below="@+id/sampleText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_above="@id/fab"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add property `layout_below` to the ListView as follows :

```
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_above="@id/fab"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
```

This would work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question properly, but one thing you can do to put your ListView below the TextView is to use `android:layout_below` attribute in ListView.